# Discrete mathematics precedence

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Say I have this statement that I want to manipulate:

$(q \wedge r) \vee s $

Knowing that $ q \wedge T \equiv q$

I add added:

$(q \wedge r) \vee s \wedge (q \vee\neg q)$

Could I now do the following?

$(q \wedge r) \vee (q \vee\neg q) \wedge s$

and distribute the values, or do I have to add parenthesis like this:

$((q \wedge r) \vee s) \wedge (q \vee\neg q)$

Answer (score 1):

Regardless of precedence, what you *did* was, to "$(q \wedge r) \vee s$", add "$q \vee \neg q$".  That is, $((q \wedge r) \vee s) \wedge (q \vee \neg q)$.  Precedence doesn't enter into it: you had already specified what subexpressions each operator was acting on.  From here, you can distribute your (top-level) conjunction over the left term's disjunction, yielding $$ 
((q \wedge r)\wedge (q \vee \neg q)) \vee (s \wedge (q \vee \neg q))
$$ and attempt to go on from there.